# What do curly braces in commands like "mkdir -p $HOME/go/{pkg,bin,src}" mean?

Tags: bash

In a [blog post](http://www.ascent.io/blog/2014/03/11/gvm-with-golang/) I have read the bash line:

```
$ mkdir -p $HOME/go/{pkg,bin,src}
```

Apparently this has the same effect as

```
$ mkdir -p $HOME/go/pkg
$ mkdir -p $HOME/go/bin
$ mkdir -p $HOME/go/src
```

So I thought that this is some form of loop, but if I try to step out of a directory to its parent parent using

```
$ cd {..,..}
```

it does not do the same as:

```
$ cd ..
$ cd ..
```

Instead, it's equivalent to:

```
$ cd ..
```

Since it is a little bit difficult to search for curly braces, and it's difficult to search for this "trick" without knowing it's name, I'm asking here for help. What exactly does this syntax mean, and why does the first command work as expected, but the second doesn't?

Comment: As an aside -- the blog you got that from was sloppy. It's better practice to either use a tilde expansion such as `~/go/{pkg,bin,src}` or to quote your expansions: `"$HOME"/go/{pkg,bin,src}`; otherwise, if your HOME value has whitespace or characters from IFS in it, it would be split into multiple arguments on that whitespace.

Comment: I assume you were using the `cd` example just as an experiment, since `cd ../..` is both shorter *and* correct :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Brace expansion expands into multiple words (which then become multiple arguments), not multiple commands. It's not

```
$ mkdir -p $HOME/go/pkg
$ mkdir -p $HOME/go/bin
$ mkdir -p $HOME/go/src
```

but instead

```
$ mkdir -p $HOME/go/pkg $HOME/go/bin $HOME/go/src
```

...which is to say: It's only useful if your command accepts multiple arguments.

See [the bash-hackers page on brace expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/brace), or [the relevant manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html).

Comment: Great, that explains it perfectly :-)! Thanks for the answer! (And I will mark it as accepted once SO let's me do this)